# database postgresql on apache tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, tomcat, jpa

I don't find the solution for my specific problem, therefore, I ask for you help.

I developed a java application using Spring, JPA/Hibernate and Vaadin. The database is on PostgreSQL.

The application on my computer run on localhost:8080 and bind the database on localhost:5432;

In order for my colleagues to use it, I need now to deploy my application on a virtal server Tomcat. The address of this Tomcat is like 10.152.487.12:8080...

I want to create a war of my application in java and deploy it on Tomcat. But, where I can put the database and how ?

Apache Tomcat allow the creation of a Postgresql server on 8080 port ?
Apache Tomcat allow the installation of a Postgresql server on 5432 like 10.152.487.12:5432 ?

Please, I need help, thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution !

Yes, I am a newbie, but I think another peoples can be in the same situation, therefore...

You open the "Remote Desktop" on windows if the server where Tomcat turn on is Windows Server. Then, you enter the IP address of the server (without the port 8080 of course). Then, you arrive on the server, you can go on Internet for download PostgreSQL (warning, desactivate the security of the browser, it not allow you to surf !).

Finally, install, enjoy !